# Python API GET Request "authorization failure" question

Tags: python, api, get, python-requests

I tried testing API request using python and I am new at this, I am able to authorize properly and get the bearer token however for the GET request it seems that it is failing.

```
import requests
import json

MainURL = "api.mysite.com/"
DataForm = {'scope': 'api-tenant',
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'client_id': 'client id',
            'client_secret': 'client secret'
            }

AuthData = requests.post(MainURL + "oauth/token", data=DataForm)
print(AuthData.text)
AuthCont = json.loads(AuthData.text)

autHeader = {'Authorization': 'Bearer' + AuthCont["access_token"], 'Accept': 'application/json'}

GetApp = requests.get(MainURL + "api/v3/applications", headers=autHeader, verify=False)

print(GetApp.text)
```

Need help.

Many thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion: 'Bearer' + AuthCont["access_token"] you have to add space in 'Bearer ' as a full form of the header is "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" and not "Authorization: BearerTOKEN"

Comment: Request returns the Access Token and additional error from PyCharm "insecureRequestWarning"  then.

{ "responseCode": "401", "errorCode": "1000", "message": "authorization failure" }

Comment: @YakovlevDenis Thank you this actually worked, only the space for the Bearer Token was causing the issues :))

Comment: glad to hear that )